# How to attach a event when i change value in dropdown using setValue method of formbuilder Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Here ParentService is a list which have a dropdown and on change event of dropdown i am firing some event, so if i change this dropdown manually than i will attach a event using ngonchange but if i am using setValue(id) to change the dropdown state how i will detect the change.

```
onNotify(value:any){
       if(value>=2){
         let parentId=this.parentServices[1].id;
         console.log(parentId);
         (<any>this.itemForm.controls).parentServices.setValue(parentId);             
       }
   }
```

Comment: So the setValue(id) doesn't trigger the change event?

Comment: It will not trigger the ngonchanges function